Turn Coordinator Behavior During Rollout - Sheppard Air Question on Coordination
The question and given answer are:

While rolling out of a left turn, if the inclinometer appears as
illustrated in A, the HCL (horizontal component of lift) and CF
(centrifugal force) vectors would be acting on the aircraft as
illustrated in:
A) 4, and more right pedal pressure is needed to center the ball.

[Figures below show: The inclinometer ball is to the right and the force vectors they selected are small HCL to the left and high CF to the right.]
If the question stated "during a sustained left hand turn" I would 100% agree. The ball is to the outside and you are skidding - too high of a yaw rate (high CF) is offset by a low bank angle (low HCL).
However, during a rollout, your inside (left in this case) aileron is creating more adverse yaw due to the downward deflected aileron. Therefore, although you are exiting a left hand turn you are effectively "slipping" to the right if the inclinometer appears as it does in (A). You need more right rudder to create more yaw to offset your downward deflected aileron. Since your yaw rate is lacking (low CF) and you are rolling right I claim the correct vectors are number 2.
I can't quite wrap my head around the right frame of reference here, or how gravity and centrifugal force come into play during rollout. What is the correct answer and why?



After writing this question and thinking a little longer I think I may get it. The downward deflected aileron is in effect doing the same thing as if I had applied too much inside rudder. Therefore, during the rollout you can have an aileron-induced skid. Doesn't matter that you are rolling right because your lift vector is still pointing left (and up) and therefore so is CF. Still hoping to hear some of your thoughts!

Exactly as you say with an aileron-induced skid. The centrifugal force (not centripetal force) is opposite the direction of the turn. So the horizontal component of lift is to the left and the centrifugal force is to the right.

You're in a left turn and the ball is to the right. This a skid, not a slip. You have decreased your angle of bank but not decreased your yaw rate enough to compensate.
The ball is feeling the forces shown in the diagram. The ball is to the right, so the force pointed right must be bigger. Therefore the answer is 2 or 4. You're in a left turn, so the horizontal component of lift (which is what lets you turn in the first place) must be to the left. So the only possible answer is 4.

Don't have enough reputation to upvote but I think I understand!

@codenoob Welcome to the site! Feel free to ask for clarifications if anything is unclear. Even with no reputation you can mark an answer as accepted by hitting the checkmark next to it- but I usually recommend holding off on that for a while to see if you get any better answers.

Thanks! Longtime reader. I'll wait and see if anyone else is working on something.

Well, do you learn how to fly after reading a book, or do you write the book after learning to fly?
It may be a bit of a trick question but ... if one were flying in a coordinated manner, why would one just roll out of a turn?
Wouldn't it make more sense to exit the turn with both yoke and rudder and stay coordinated?
It seems you've figured out that the lower aileron will create adverse yaw, and rudder must be applied to compensate.

step on the ball

But the important lesson here, especially when low and slow, is not to be uncoordinated when turning, especially with the inside aileron down.
If the inside, lower wing stalls, the plane will roll into the turn.  At pattern altitude, it is generally non-recoverable.
